# How to train a neural network with a string output

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm very new to neural network but I'm doing a project where we have a given data set with some flowers petals dimensions and the species it is and I have to train a neural network using that but the all the previous neural network i have done were all with numbers and no strings to process, so now I don't know how to train the neural network using the species names, if i can use the array with the species names or if i need to assign a integer to each different species and then use that to train the neural network.

Comment: It sounds like you need a guide or tutorial, which Stack Overflow is not. Please see: [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

The latter - you need to encode the categorical variable, i.e. assign a numeric label (*integer*) to each string (or species) to be able to use it to train a neural network.

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out with the encoding

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks only work with numerical values, so every type of data needs to be converted to numerical values. Often, they are stored in tensors (hence the name TensorFlow).

Assuming you are doing Iris classification, here is how you can convert the string labels to int labels:

```py
labels = {'Iris-setosa': 0, 'Iris-versicolor': 1, 'Iris-virginica': 2}
target = [labels[label] for label in target]
target = keras.utils.to_categorical(target)
```

where target initially is a [Pandas](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/index.htm) dataframe.

Comment: But after i do a predict with dataframe like that i get an array with 3 columns and a bunch of float values that seem to be between 0 and 2 so im guessing those are the values of how likely they are a certain specie right? if so is there a way to get that array and transform those floats back to the label corresponding to the likelihood of being a certain specie

Comment: Yes, that is when you want to use softmax and argmax. Softmax is a certain activation function and scales every value to a range from 0 to 1 and makes all the values sum up to 1. This way, these value can be used as probabilities of an input belonging to a certain class. To get the label, you would use argmax, which returns the index of the node with the highest activation (computed by softmax). This gives you an integer which you can use as an index for the labels dict.